# Is there a name for this pipelining-like parallelization method?

Tags: multithreading, performance, optimization

Recently, I was trying to optimize a single-threaded loop that at its core boils down to something like

```
while (true)
{
   a = A(x)
   b = B(a)
   c = C(b)
}
```

In other words, every step depends on the result of the previous step. Each of these functions performs CPU intensive operations.

I ended up creating 2 queues and 2 new threads and decoupled it so that the original thread does

```
/* on existing thread */ while (true) queue1.Enqueue(A(x))
/* on new thread #1 */   while (true) queue2.Enqueue(B(queue1.Dequeue()))
/* on new thread #2 */   while (true) c = B(queue2.Dequeue()))
```

Now the 3 functions can run in parallel, making better use of multiple cores.

It seems so basic, there must be a name for it. I cannot find it though. It highly resembles what [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) does, only this is a parallelization technique for threads.

Comment: I would say it is pipelining.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly straightforward producer/consumer setup.

Comment: @tia Thanks, your answer led me to google a bit deeper, and I seem to have found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27957276/709537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more thorough web searching revealed it is called **Pipeline Parallelism** [by](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mahlke/courses/583f12/reading/gordon_asplos06.pdf) [some](http://www.futurechips.org/parallel-programming-2/parallel-programming-clarifying-pipeline-parallelism.html). Which is a descriptive name.

On one of the pages linked to above, there's also an intuitive visualization of the method:

[image: Pipeline Parallelism]